# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel text disappear when cell textLabel is too long

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When the text in my TableViewCell is really long, the detailTextLabel disappears. I know `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` is deprecated with iOS 6, so I tried this:

`cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode =  NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;`

That didn't work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

The detailTextLabel is set to "Right Detail" in my Storyboard, which is `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`.

Comment: Try setting that on the `detailTextLabel` since that is where the problem is.

Comment: Is your cell's style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` or `...Value1` or `...Value2`? If it is `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, it doesn't have the subtitle.

Comment: @Jsdodgers It's `...Value1`.

Comment: @rmaddy - Tried it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the way the Value1 type of cell works. The text label apparently has no fixed size to keep it from obscuring the detail label. The easiest way to fix this is to make your own custom cell with 2 labels. Give the detail label a fixed size and a constraint to the right side of the cell, and give the text label a constraint to the left side and a spacing constraint to the detail label (but no fixed size).

Comment: Ok; I was hoping there was a different way, but I'll try working with that.